# How to loop somepart of function in flutter?

Tags: flutter, function, loops, for-loop

I want to loop some part of function base on widget.menuItem.category.length, I am new in flutter.
Here is my current code :

```
_buildContentView({BuildContext context}) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        _buildMenuItemImage(),
        Container(
          child: Text(widget.menuItem.name,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 12, bottom: 8),
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text(widget.menuItem.itemDescription,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 12, bottom: 8),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Text('Select ' + widget.menuItem.category[0]),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 6),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text('Select ' +
                  _qty.toString() +
                  ' item (' +
                  _qty.toString() +
                  '/' +
                  widget.menuItem.setMenuItems.length.toString() +
                  ')'),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 6),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        _buildSetMenusView(setMenuItems: widget.menuItem.setMenuItems),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12, top: 8, bottom: 12),
          child: _buildActionButtons(context: context),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

I want to loop this part :

```
Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Text('Select ' + widget.menuItem.category[0]),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 6),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text('Select ' +
                  _qty.toString() +
                  ' item (' +
                  _qty.toString() +
                  '/' +
                  widget.menuItem.setMenuItems.length.toString() +
                  ')'),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 6),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        _buildSetMenusView(setMenuItems: widget.menuItem.setMenuItems),
```

I tried with this code but failed, it did not show on simulator (blank):

```
for(var i = 0; i < widget.menuItem.category.length; i++){
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Text('Select ' + widget.menuItem.category[i]),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 6),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text('Select ' +
                  _qty.toString() +
                  ' item (' +
                  _qty.toString() +
                  '/' +
                  widget.menuItem.setMenuItems.length.toString() +
                  ')'),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 6),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        _buildSetMenusView(setMenuItems: widget.menuItem.setMenuItems),
}
```

What is the correct code to loop this part in flutter? please help me repair this flutter loop code

Comment: try to debug/print `widget.menuItem.category.length` if it is greater than 0

Comment: yes, it is greater than 0

Comment: You like to loop inside column?

Comment: because only somepart of column that i need to loop

Comment: ok, you can use spreed operator as I've posted. (It doesnt have `{..}` on for loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are looking inside Column and like to return multiple widget, you can use spreed operator for this.

```dart
for(var i = 0; i < widget.menuItem.category.length; i++)
  ...[
      Row(),
      _buildSetMenusView()
     ],
```

Also you can return another Column.

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right then you have to wrap a widget inside a `ListView.builder` in Flutter, you need to follow a few steps. `ListView.builder` is a great choice when you have a large number of children widgets and you want to build them on-demand, as it helps with performance optimization. Here's how you can wrap a widget inside a `ListView.builder`:

1. **Import Flutter Material:** First, make sure you have imported the necessary Flutter material library in your Dart file.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

2. **Create a ListView.builder:** Define a `ListView.builder` widget. This widget takes a builder function that generates the list items dynamically based on the index.

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: itemCount, // Replace itemCount with the actual number of items you have.
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    // Here, you can return a widget for each list item based on the index.
    return YourListItemWidget(index); // Replace YourListItemWidget with your custom widget.
  },
)
```

3. **Create Your Custom List Item Widget:** You'll need to create a custom widget for each item in the list. This is where you can define the layout and design of your list items.

```dart
class YourListItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;

  YourListItemWidget(this.index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('Item $index'), // Customize this based on your data.
      // Add other widgets and styling as needed.
    );
  }
}
```

4. **Replace 'itemCount' and 'YourListItemWidget' with Your Data:** In the `ListView.builder`, replace `itemCount` with the actual number of items you have in your list, and replace `YourListItemWidget` with your custom list item widget.
5. **Display the ListView.builder:** Finally, add your `ListView.builder` to your widget tree in the appropriate part of your Flutter app.

Here's a complete example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('ListView.builder Example'),
        ),
        body: MyListView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyListView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 20, // Replace with the actual number of items.
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return YourListItemWidget(index); // Replace with your custom widget.
      },
    );
  }
}

class YourListItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;

  YourListItemWidget(this.index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('Item $index'), // Customize this based on your data.
      // Add other widgets and styling as needed.
    );
  }
}
```

Replace the `itemCount` and the content of `YourListItemWidget` with your actual data and custom widget as needed. This will allow you to create a scrollable list of items efficiently using `ListView.builder` in Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

To loop through a part of your function based on the widget.menuItem.category length, you can use a ListView.builder or a Column with a loop. Here's how you can do it using a Column:

```
_buildContentView(BuildContext context) {
  List<Widget> rows = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < widget.menuItem.category.length; i++) {
    rows.add(
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Text('Select ' + widget.menuItem.category[i]),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 6),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Text('Select ' +
                _qty.toString() +
                ' item (' +
                _qty.toString() +
                '/' +
                widget.menuItem.setMenuItems.length.toString() +
                ')'),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 6),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
    rows.add(_buildSetMenusView(setMenuItems: widget.menuItem.setMenuItems));
  }

  return Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      _buildMenuItemImage(),
      Container(
        child: Text(widget.menuItem.name,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 12, bottom: 8),
      ),
      Container(
        child: Text(widget.menuItem.itemDescription,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 12, bottom: 8),
      ),
      ...rows, // Use the spread operator to add the list of rows
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12, top: 8, bottom: 12),
        child: _buildActionButtons(context: context),
      )
    ],
  );
}
```